# Javascript - Text input number validation for positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript, validation

I have an input which is a text field and I want the user to only be able to enter positive and negative numbers into this field. I have found other answers to this however they allow the minus sign to be entered at any point in the string where as I only want the minus sign to be entered at the first position of the string.

I also want the user to be able to use the keyboard arrow keys and any keyboard shortcuts for copying, cutting, pasting and selecting etc.

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289810/javascript-limit-text-field-to-positive-and-negative-numbers

Comment: if you're using only `html5` compliant browsers you can use the `pattern` attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern

Comment: @haxxxton that's fine but I need a pattern to check

Comment: @AJB this seems an awfully long winded way to achieve the goal

Comment: @midda25, do you allow decimals?

Comment: @haxxxton no decimals

Comment: @midda25, `^\-?[0-9]+$` this patten says the value may begin with a `-` or not, and may contain any count of numbers only. The alternative to a no decimal solution would be to use the `step` attribute to limit input to whole numbers up or down https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-step (if you have a min or max you could all those attributes too)

Comment: @midda25, i should note that this will only restrict the `submission` of the form, not limit the input to only allow those characters to be pressed, if your intention is to ignore user input not matching the pattern you will need to use a JS solution: for example https://jsfiddle.net/2k6d3w5w/

Comment: @haxxxton that js fiddle isn't working.

Comment: @haxxton ignoring user input (keystrokes) is a horrible user experience. Many users will think their keyboards are broken.